# How to remove NaN if remove value from the field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an input filed in decimal format, as per below.
If i key in the value in field 1 (ex: 100.00) then i want to remove the value. But on field 1 will return NaN. How to make field 1 to return empty if i remove/blank on the field 1?

```js
$('input.Currency').on('blur', function() {
        const value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
        this.value = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
            style: 'decimal',
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field 1<input type="tel" class="Currency">
<br>
Field 2<input type="tel" class="Currency">
```

Comment: your question is really vague please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your on-blur function, you have to check whether the value is **NaN**. If it is then replace it with empty value.

```js
$('input.Currency').on('blur', function() {
  let value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
  value = parseFloat(value);
  if (isNaN(value))
    this.value = '';
  else
    this.value = value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      style: 'decimal',
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field 1<input type="tel" class="Currency">
<br>
Field 2<input type="tel" class="Currency">
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: sorry john, but when i try to put more than 4 digits, it will return empty also, can u help me

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? this.value.replace(/,/g, '');

Comment: Removes all `,` - standard practice when your input contains 1000 separators (comma) as parseFloat doesn't recognise these, ie "1,234" -> 1234

Comment: This fails with values >999 because `isNaN(this.value)` checks **after the value has been reformatted**, so now contains separator commas again and is therefore not a valid "number".

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `value` is NaN *before* formatting it.

```js
$('input.Currency').on('blur', function() {
  let value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
  value = parseFloat(value);
  if (isNaN(value))
    this.value = '';
  else
    this.value = value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      style: 'decimal',
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field 1<input type="tel" class="Currency">
<br> 
Field 2<input type="tel" class="Currency">
```