# How to format currency while typing, but you also want to use that input as a number after formatting (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I am trying to build an online calculator and I wanted to format my input into currency while typing.

On this website: https://www.ratehub.ca/cmhc-mortgage-insurance the asking price input box is similar to what I would like to achieve.

I have tried this code here:

```
$("#formattedNumberField").on('keyup', function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
$(this).val(n.toLocaleString());
//do something else as per updated question
myFunc(); //call another function too
});
```

But it would display NaN after typing a number and deleting it, also I can not use the formatted number for future calculation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the Jquery.inputmask plugin [here](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/).

Comment: Would it be possible to add more info ? Perhaps some more code ? HTML lines ?

Comment: please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897119/how-to-remove-nan-if-remove-value-from-the-field